# How would I connect a wireless microphone to a speaker and a computer. Then have that same computer also use that speaker

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, microphone, speakers, obs-studio

At work, they assigned me a task to integrate people from zoom into our live events.

So far I have mics and video sources running through OBS. The video and sound are then sent to Zoom via fakeOBSCamera and virtual cable(using an OBS audio monitor plugin). I have the audio output of Zoom connected to my headphones to monitor the Zoom participants, and when they are ready to speak I change the output to the loudspeaker, but there's my problem. I also want the presenters to be able to use the loudspeaker as well.

How do I make my loudspeaker share my Zoom output and presenter output, while also having my presenter's microphone audio go directly to OBS for Zoom participants?

I haven't bought any hardware yet so I'm open to hardware recommendations and setups. Right now I'm in the planning stages of figuring out how to do this.

edit: I have tried running the presenter microphone from my computer to a monitored output, but there's a noticeable delay that would mess up a presenter.

Answer (score 0):

I figured for me to directly get the audio input from my Bluetooth mic to my speaker and pc, I run the mic aux to a "3.5mm Stereo Audio Switch Audio Switcher Passive Speaker Headphone Manual Selector Splitter Box" and have one end connected to my computer and the other end connected to the speaker.